# Duplicate Transfers taking place on Windows Server with nuSoap on Linux Server

Tags: php, transfer, nusoap

I have successfully set up nuSoap on a Linux server where a portal is handshaking with a Windows Server of a Vendor. Everything is working fine on our end. Visitors can come from Vendor website and be automatically logged into our portal. But the Vendors are saying the following: "I see duplicates so it appears that the issue might be that the transfers are being used more than once.  Only one transfer is allowed per request."

I have no clue what they are talking about and why everything is working fine on our side but their system is saying that there are more than one transfer taking place. Can anyone point me in any direction?

I know this is a vague question. But I do not know where to begin to look to try to solve something that is showing up on their end.

Comment: Gather more detail from your Vendors, about the problem; ask them for some rough guidance for proof of duplicate transferrs, how they are picking it up? Just ask enough questions so you can replicate this bug within your own local setup to fix.

Comment: Thanks! I had already done that but they have not responded yet. So I will wait until I hear from them. I showed them the data results of the handshake. Once they mentioned that, "Could it be going to both staging and production environments?" Thanks again!

Comment: You need to get enough information from the people which are reporting the bug; then follow a troupleshooting process which you establish yourself